# Unique CPU id in java

Tags: java

I want to sale my application developed in JAVA. I'm looking for a way to get unique computer id, CPU id or motherboard id to which I can allow my application to run. How to identify the computer in java? I could not use mac address because my application work in environment where internet is not available.

Comment: @Anatoly thanks this is exactly for what i was searching!

Comment: You should know that there is no problem in decompiling your source and to change the stored ID. You should look for some ways to protect your source code from being altered.